# "Realizing that, despite..." vs "realizing despite...that."

Tags: grammar, writing-style

What's the correct form? Example:

> I smiled, realizing that, despite her craziness, I missed her.
>
> I smiled, realizing, despite her craziness, that I missed her.

Is there any grammatical/stylistic rule I can use in the future to avoid this kind of confusion?

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct, but they do not mean the same.

> I smiled, realizing that[, despite her craziness, I missed her].

Even though she's crazy, you missed her.

> I smiled, [realizing, despite her craziness,] that I missed her.

Even though she's crazy, you realized something (that you missed her).

In the second version, I would omit the second and third comma but I guess that is a style choice.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about it like that. I guess the second case doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @janoChen: actually, the second case could make sense in a slightly different situation. “She was screaming at the top of her lungs. Still, despite her craziness, I realized her words made sense.” But it may be far-fetched.